# SPFx development with Reactide, instead of the SPFx Workbench?

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

Before I spend more time on this to evaluate how this tools stacks up to the SPFx Workbench..

**Question:** Is anyone else following, or tried to use Reactide with SPFx?

---

source: https://github.com/reactide/reactide

#### Reactide is the first dedicated IDE for React web application development

Reactide is a cross-platform desktop application that offers a custom simulator, making build-tool and server configuration unnecessary. Reactide brings development back to the days where opening a single file instantly renders the project in the browser. With Reactide, developers can achieve the same simplicity with a single React JSX file while still utilizing the power of React.

Reactide is in active development. Please follow this repo for contribution guidelines and our development road map.

[image]

### Get right to coding

Reactide runs an integrated Node server and custom browser simulator, which eliminates the need to configure servers, build-tools, and even offers hot module reloading right out of the box. Projects developed in Reactide are build-tool agnostic. As projects evolve, the developer only needs to add necessary dependencies without having to make decisions before coding has even started.

### State flow visualization

Managing state across a complex web of React components is the biggest pain point of developing React apps. Reactide offers the first visual editing solution for today's most powerful visual UI engine. By navigating through a live representation of  the architecture of a project, developers can quickly identify and jump to relevant components and edit them on the fly.

### Synchronized property and style controls

Code is the representation of user interfaces, but writing code rarely ever resembles it. By cross-utilizing Reactide’s tools, properties and styles can be edited through straightforward GUI controls that provide immediate feedback in the browser simulator. The cumbersome process of having to wait and transpile every minor edit to a project is now instant.

### Contributors

[Jin Choi](https://github.com/jinihendrix) | [Mark Marcelo](https://github.com/markmarcelo) | [Bita Djaghouri](https://github.com/bitadj)